# Gitlab-CI custom variable

Tags: gitlab-ci

I declare a custom variable in gitlab-ci.yml like so:

```
variables:
  APP_NAME: moodleadmin
```

Then I try to use it in a script:

```
  script:
    - ssh root@devsb01 'service $APP_NAME stop'
```

But it's not replaced, here is the CI log:

```
$ ssh root@devsb01 'service $APP_NAME stop'
```

Which lead to following error:

```
stop: unrecognized service
```

What is the correct way to use the variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which image you are using, but I assume it's something that provides a default bash shell where inside single quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception.

You have to use the double quote:

```
script:
    - ssh root@devsb01 "service $APP_NAME stop"
```